# How can I customize a WordPress theme before it's downloaded?

Tags: php, theme-development, customization

So I couldn't think of a way to make the title more clear, sorry. Here's the idea:

I want to offer a theme for download from my site and would like to be able to have a user customize the theme in advance before they download it, with the final download only having the options they've specified. For example, they may want a custom post type of 'Books' with fields of Author, Year Published, Cover, Description, Rating. Additionally, they may want several different page templates, but not all that I'm offering. Pre-define metaboxes for featured image manipulation, etc, etc.

I know that isn't exactly WP related, but I don't even know where to start. Thoughts, ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at how Foundation handles this - sounds like their download is exactly like what you're asking for. Although with your particular example I wouldn't bundle CPTs in the theme - if they change the theme later they'll still likely want to keep that content. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/

Comment: That was the example that got me thinking about this. If they can build their download on the fly, I imagine this should be doable as well.

Very good point wrt: CPT. So that simplifies things greatly, which may mean I could do it with Gulp/Grunt compiling just the CSS on the fly and handling everything else with the WP Customizer.

Comment: You may be able to get some inspiration from the [underscores.me](http://underscores.me/) website and [the corresponding repository on gitbub](https://github.com/Automattic/underscores.me).